# Convert asterisks to bold or italic tags

Tags: java, android

I want to convert text between markdown style bold/italics to html bold/italics. Here's an example:

```
**Bold text** is bold, *italic* text is italicized.
```

Should go to:

```
<b>Bold text</b> is bold, <i>italic</i> text is italicized.
```

I looked elsewhere on SO, but most questions recommended a parsing library. However, I think using a library would be unsuitable for the following reasons:

- I'm trying to keep the code base as small as possible
- A parser will have too many features!
- I want to make it as fast & lightweight as possible

How should I go about converting these tags then?

Comment: Parse it yourself then? It's not terribly difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to do this myself in the past thinking exactly as you have trying to hand bake the solution. The number of exceptions you have to cater for once you add one or two more markups becomes very complex. I ended up re-inventing the wheel in a much less eficent manner. I opted to adopt one of the parsing libraries and never looked back.

> A parser will have too many features!

You can get some parsers that let you define your own markup language.  This is what I opted for.  I did it in .Net so I can't suggest a Java version.

> I want to make it as fast & lightweight as possible

Any parsing library will be more efficient than your own and unless you're parsing many MBs of data I don't think you'll notice much difference.  They have usually spent much more time on making it efficient that I maybe you would be willing to.

I know this isn't an "answer" as such, but I hope I save you some time (and delay the onset of gray hair) or point you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm with you on this one. I've attempted to write my own parsers, and I've seen others do it too. They rarely turn out to be particularly small, fast, or readable.